# How to replace NaN in python DataFrame with data from crosstab

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, crosstab

Good morning I'm new to pandas. I have a DataFrame called df that has 4 columns: Age, Survived, Pclass and Sex (PassengerID = index). A portion of the Age fields = NaN

```
             Age  Survived  Pclass     Sex
PassengerId                             
6            NaN         0       3    male
18           NaN         1       2    male
20           NaN         1       3  female
27           NaN         0       3    male
29           NaN         1       3  female
```

I'd like to replace the Age NaN with data from a crosstab.

```
mean_val = pd.crosstab(index=df["Survived"],columns[df['Sex'],df['Pclass']],values=df['Age'],aggfunc=np.mean)
```

which produces the following:

```
    Sex          female                             male                      
Pclass            1          2          3          1          2          3
Survived                                                                  
0         25.666667  36.000000  23.818182  44.581967  33.369048  27.255814
1         34.939024  28.080882  19.329787  36.248000  16.022000  22.274211
```

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
df['Age'] = mean_val[[df['Sex']][df['Pclass']][df['Survived']]]
```

Where I'm using the crosstab as a look up for the specific passenger. The outcome would look like this:

```
             Age        Survived  Pclass     Sex
PassengerId                             
6            27.255814         0       3    male
18           16.022000         1       2    male
20           19.329787         1       3  female
27           27.255814         0       3    male
29           19.329787         1       3  female
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and replace `NaN`s by `mean`s per groups:

```
df['Age'] = (df.groupby(['Survived','Sex','Pclass'])['Age']
               .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())))
```

If want use `mean_val` as input:

```
df = df.join(mean_val.unstack().rename('tmp'), ['Sex','Pclass','Survived'])
df['Age'] = df['Age'].combine_first(df['tmp'])
df = df.drop('tmp', axis=1)
```

**Sample**:

```
c = ['PassengerId','Age','Survived','Pclass','Sex']
df = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId': [6, 18, 20, 27, 29, 16, 118, 120, 127, 129], 
                   'Age': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 
                           2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0], 
                   'Survived': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
                   'Pclass': [3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                   'Sex': ['male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 
                           'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female']},
                   columns=c)

print (df)
   PassengerId  Age  Survived  Pclass     Sex
0            6  NaN         0       3    male
1           18  NaN         1       2    male
2           20  NaN         1       3  female
3           27  NaN         0       3    male
4           29  NaN         1       3  female
5           16  2.0         0       3    male
6          118  3.0         1       2    male
7          120  4.0         1       3  female
8          127  3.0         0       3    male
9          129  4.0         1       3  female
```

---

```
mean_val = pd.crosstab(index=df["Survived"],columns=[df['Sex'],df['Pclass']],values=df['Age'],aggfunc=np.mean)
print (mean_val)
Sex      female male     
Pclass        3    2    3
Survived                 
0           NaN  NaN  2.5
1           4.0  3.0  NaN

df = df.join(mean_val.unstack().rename('tmp'), ['Sex','Pclass','Survived'])
df['Age'] = df['Age'].combine_first(df['tmp'])
df = df.drop('tmp', axis=1)
print (df)
   PassengerId  Age  Survived  Pclass     Sex
0            6  2.5         0       3    male
1           18  3.0         1       2    male
2           20  4.0         1       3  female
3           27  2.5         0       3    male
4           29  4.0         1       3  female
5           16  2.0         0       3    male
6          118  3.0         1       2    male
7          120  4.0         1       3  female
8          127  3.0         0       3    male
9          129  4.0         1       3  female
```

---

```
df['Age'] = (df.groupby(['Survived','Sex','Pclass'])['Age']
               .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())))

print (df)
   PassengerId  Age  Survived  Pclass     Sex
0            6  2.5         0       3    male
1           18  3.0         1       2    male
2           20  4.0         1       3  female
3           27  2.5         0       3    male
4           29  4.0         1       3  female
5           16  2.0         0       3    male
6          118  3.0         1       2    male
7          120  4.0         1       3  female
8          127  3.0         0       3    male
9          129  4.0         1       3  female
```